# How to sum 4D matrices in MATLAB along one coordinate?

Tags: matlab

I do not know what happened to me but I cannot find the way to do it. It seems easy though.

I have a 4D matrix `A=rand(4, 3, 3, 3)` and I would like to sum these matrices along the 3rd coordinates.

```
A = rand(4, 3, 3, 3);

S1 = A(:,:,1,1)+A(:,:,1,2)+A(:,:,1,3);

S2 = A(:,:,2,1)+A(:,:,2,2)+A(:,:,2,3);

S3 = A(:,:,3,1)+A(:,:,3,2)+A(:,:,3,3);
```

How to do this in general?

Comment: Isn't that just `sum(A,3)` ?

Comment: Yes it is. I knew that it is something easy. Thanks.

Comment: @LuisMendo, I prefer it when questions that are answered also appear answered on the front page, even when the answer is very simple, so I posted your comment (+ some additional info) as an answer. I don't do it for rep, so I made it Community Wiki. Please let me know if you want to make your comment an answer and I will of course remove my answer =)

Comment: @RoberP Good idea. I also like solved questions to appear as closed in the front page. For me it's ok. Thanks for caring :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum along the n'th dimension, you can use the second argument to `sum` like this:

```
s = sum(A,n);
```

thus in your case, to sum along the third dimension:

```
s = sum(A,3);
```